# With terminal on Macbook pro why can't I use the "delete button" to remove text on 'nled' command

Tags: macos, terminal, command

I'm kind of confuse a little bit, I just got my Macbook Pro today and trying to do the C language programming through terminal and I use to use PC [Windows] and the "delete button" working as a backspace for Windows

now I'm on terminal before get into `nled` it was working normal but after `nled` command the delete button isn't effect anymore

is there a way to remove the text in `nled` ?? I even tried with fn+delete and isnot working still

Comment: I just figure it out that I can use the same key to delete/remove text in `nled editor' on terminal by using `ctrl+h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal has a preference setting to have the Delete key send Control-H instead of the usual delete character (ASCII DEL 0x7F):

> **Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Advanced > Delete sends Ctrl-H**

If you're going to be using `nled` often, you can create a custom settings profile just for running `nled`. Select an existing profile (e.g., Basic) and choose **Duplicate Settings** from the action menu (the gear icon at the bottom of the profile list). Customize the "Delete" preference, and then put the `nled` command in:

> **Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Shell > Run command**

Enable the "Run command" checkbox, and possibly also "Run inside shell". Now you can just choose this new profile from the **Shell > New Tab/Window** submenus and it will create a new terminal and run the `nled` command with the customized Delete behavior.